# Validate string within short range

Tags: c++, validation

I have a short integer in a string. For Eg: "123456". Is there any API to check whether the string contains a valid number in the range of unsigned short?

Thanks!

Comment: The by far easiest way to check if a number is in a range should be converting it into an integer (a sufficently large integer type, e.g. `long`) and using the comparision operators...

Comment: You mean other than `errno=0; strtoul( str, 0, 10 ) <= USHRT_MAX && !errno`?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the stream operators to input the number:

```
istringstream istr("12346");
short s;
if ((istr >> s) and istr.eof())
    cout << "valid: " << s << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid" << endl;
```

(Needs the header `sstream`.)

Comment: -1 this will work not always. Consider if your string is "1542 2451". Your program will print "valid : 1542".

Comment: @Mihran - and how is this broken? 1542 is a valid short AFAIK. The OP did not mention there being multiple numbers in the string - as such, this solution is fine...

Comment: I think OP wants to check:
1. If string contains integer number 2. If it in short ranges.
But this answer does not meet with first condition.

Comment: @Mihran: well, simply check for `eof` afterwards. See amended answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast) :

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s("12346");
  try {
    boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(s);
    std::cout << "valid\n";
  } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
    std::cout << "invalid\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use strtol to both convert the number and to check if it was a valid number string, using the "endptr" parameter.  Then you could convert it to a short and check for equality.