# How do I handle overflow / underflow when converting std::string to integer?

Tags: c++, types, overflow

I'm trying to convert a numeric **std::string** to an **integer** using `std::istringstream`

```
std::istringstream convertor;

convertor.str(mystring);
convertor >> myint;
```

I want to throw an exception if the numeric string is over (or under) the limits of an integer, but I don't know what is the best way to do so. I wonder if there is something specific to std::istringstream or something else made especially for this purpose, or do I have to use dirty (it seems dirty at least :) ) ways with `numeric_limits` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `basic_ios` can be set up to indicate the various categories of error by setting an internal flag (which you must then check) *or* by throwing an exception. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Comment: `std::stoi` does this automatically.

Comment: Look at [this example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/vhB0T$0).

Comment: You may find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045693/negative-numeric-string-e-g-10-to-unsigned-short

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate string within short range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834439/validate-string-within-short-range)

Comment: Do you need to partially convert an input or not ? By that I mean, does your input solely represent a number (`"12345"`) or may the number be followed by something else entirely (`"12345foo"`) ? It's important to assert whether you should still be able to read `foo` afterward in the latter case or whether it's an eroneous input; as this changes which solutions are acceptable.

Comment: If you like overkill, you could use a bignum library like this one http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/numerics.html and then convert the arbitrary integer back to your favorite int type.

Comment: My input is always valid. In fact, I have to parse an asm file with a given grammar and my function always receives a valid string, except the number can be higher or lower than limits of the type... I just updated my message to show you a strange bug I have with your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::istringstream convertor;
convertor.str(mystring);
if(!(convertor >> myint)) {
    thow std::invalid_argument();
}
```

It should be noted such a function is already available in the standard library. (C++11)

```
it=std::stoi(my_string);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Furthermore this is arguably this is exception abuse as a precondition to the function is that `mystring` should represent a integer value, and if that is not a precondition then it is a part of the functions normal flow control to handle the case where it is not.

I would probably write:

```
std::pair<bool, int> try_to_int(const std::string& str);
```

Or a boost::optional would work well here too

Comment: Only if you have C++11 (which isn't the case of most people.)

Comment: @JamesKanze "which isn't the case of most people" says who? Also the doc I linked also mentions that fact.

Comment: I wonder @111111 what is in your (or the standards) opinion the correct way to handle invalid input? Just do some undefined behaviour?

Comment: `out_of_range` is a fishy thing to throw if the stream contains `"quack"`, which is why `stoi` can also throw `invalid_argument`.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I don't think the standard says much on the matter, I personally write asserts for invalid input, because if I give invalid input to a function then that IS a bug.

Comment: @111111 Says reality.  Most compilers don't support C++11, and those that do don't support it completely or well.  And very few people can use the latest version of the compiler; most companies won't want to use a new major version until there've been a few patch releases.  (There business isn't testing compilers.)

Comment: @aschepler yes, you are right, I was crudely copying that from the stoi doc. I guess std::invalid_argument is slightly better. As I said, I would make a try function anyway.

Comment: @JonasWielicki anyway, if you wanted your function to discern the input, that is when I start using "try" functions which turn a tuple, pair of optional type.

Comment: @JamesKanze All the mainstream compilers have enough C++11 implemented to use std::stoi. If someone is constrained by workplace requirements then they would make that clear in their question. The worst case is that they try it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @111111 So you basically test twice, once in the try-function and once in the function which does the actual convert (inside of an assert, which can be removed at compile-time if desired)?

Comment: @JulienFouilhé which method, I mentioned a few? (or do you mean all -- because `std::istringstream` is less a part of the standard than `std::invalid_argument`.

Comment: I meant std::stoi. The one with invalid_argument displays the same error I added to my message. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @111111 Not everyone can use the latest version of the compiler (and I don't have access to all of the "mainstream" compilers to know, but I have had problems with C++11 support with the version of g++ I use).  As a general rule, it's best to assume that the poster can't count on C++11 unless he says so, as that's the reality in the working world.

Comment: @JamesKanze I disagree, I do and will continue to give information out according to the *current* standard and what the current mainstream compilers and stdlib have implemented. Unless there is some SO reason not to or the OP has said that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to C++11 features, try `std::stoi(my_string);`

If you do not, but have access to boost libraries, try:

```
std::string str("112211"); 
int x = 0;
try
{
    x = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
}
(catch boost::bad_lexical_cast&)
{
}
```

boost::lexical cast is defined (for the generic case at least), to use an `istringstream` internally (If you override `std::istream& operator>>` for `your_type`, you will be able to read your type with `lexical_cast<your_type>(string)`);

If you do not have access to boost either, roll your own (others in this thread have already pointed out how to set iostreams to throw exceptions).

edit: rolling your own:

```
template<typename T>
T lexical_cast<T>(const std::string & str)
{
    std::istringstream buffer(str);
    buffer.exceptions(std::istringstream::failbit);
    T retval;
    buffer >> retval;
    return retval;
}
```

You can particularize this for value types that do not support iostream io.

Comment: I can't use this method neither... I am not allowed to use boost library.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I found the solution in the comments of my question:

```
std::istringstream convertor;

convertor.str("16");
convertor >> myint;
if (convertor.fail())
    std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
```

Or, to throw an exception:

```
std::istringstream convertor;

convertor.exceptions(std::istringstream::failbit);
convertor.str("16");
convertor >> myint;
```